LazyVim omnisharp formatting
Im using LazyVim on MacOs and have added the omnisharp lsp plugin:
return {
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
  opts = {
    servers = {
      omnisharp = {
        handlers = {
          ["textDocument/definition"] = require("omnisharp_extended").definition_handler,
          ["textDocument/typeDefinition"] = require("omnisharp_extended").type_definition_handler,
          ["textDocument/references"] = require("omnisharp_extended").references_handler,
          ["textDocument/implementation"] = require("omnisharp_extended").implementation_handler,
        },
        keys = {
          {
            "gi",
            function()
              require("omnisharp_extended").telescope_lsp_definitions()
            end,
            desc = "Goto Definition",
          },
          {
            "gd",
            function()
              require("omnisharp_extended").telescope_lsp_implementation()
            end,
            desc = "Goto Implementation",
          },
        },
        enable_roslyn_analyzers = true,
        organize_imports_on_format = true,
        enable_import_completion = true,
      },
    },
  },
}

The issue is the formatting, :LspInfo shows correct information about the LSP loaded. But ~/.omnisharp/omnisharp.json doesnt seem to effect.
Heres my omnisharp.json:
{
  "RoslynExtensionsOptions": {
    "enableDecompilationSupport": true
  },
  "FormattingOptions": {
    "EnableEditorConfigSupport": false,
    "TabSize": 4,
    "InsertSpaces": true
    "NewLinesForBracesInMethods": true,
    "NewLinesForBracesInTypes": true,
    "NewLinesForBracesInProperties": true,
    "NewLinesForBracesInControlBlocks": true
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  }
}

I've also tried to add directly settings into omni-lsp.lua file but didnt work, the only thing i got to change my formatting was to add a .editorconfig into my project, but couldnt format accordinly to example with that.
Any suggestions?
The issue is basically that i want:
var response = 
   _service.MyCall()
   .FirstOrDefault()
   ?? throw new CustomException("Ops!");

To be formatted like (like i had in VSCode):
var response = _service
   .MyCall()
   .FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new CustomException("Ops!");

//or

var response = _service.MyCall()
   .FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new CustomException("Ops!");

